# Android LinearLayout button alignment

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to align cancel and save button to `center`. But the below code aligns buttons to `center_vertical`, but buttons are not aligned center horizontally. Rather they are aligned to left. How can I align these buttons to the center both horizontally and vertically?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i cant see any buttons in your layout?Can you post your entire XML file

Comment: Where are the button widgets declared?

Comment: Apply `android:gravity="center"` to your `LinearLayout`.

Comment: com.ecw.healow.mom.widget.TypefaceTextView are buttons. :)

Comment: Are `TypefaceTextView` your custom `Button`s?? Also you are using `android:layout_weight="1"` property so you need to apply width `0dp` instead of `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llCardButtom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.ecw.healow.mom.widget.TypefaceTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            obs:typefaceVariant="titillium_web_regular" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mom_card_button_vert_line"
            android:contentDescription="@string/divider" />

        <com.ecw.healow.mom.widget.TypefaceTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            obs:typefaceVariant="titillium_web_regular" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use layout_weight attribute to do this kind of design.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is to use the attribute:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

on the linear layout not on the individual contents.